# Alarm Panel EOLR ohms

Tags: resistors

I have an alarm system panel that uses 1000 ohms EOLR (10%, 1/2 watt). One of them has failed and I would like to know if I can replace it with a 1500 ohms (5%, 1/2 watt) EOLR. Is this acceptable or MUST it be replace with an 1000 ohms (5% or 10%, 1/2 watt) EOLR if all the other EOLRs remain as the original 1000 ohms EOLRs?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with three 1500ohm resistors, if you can find a way to cram them in:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEyIvr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is more than I want to do so I will probably replace the one resistor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Different R values on the line indicate a security fault in a particular zone where each zone may have a unique value.

a single resistor allows the system to sense if the circuit is secure, open, or shorted.

Secure means exactly 1K 1000 ohms EOLR (10%, 1/2 watt) maybe 15% but not 50% like 1500 ohms.

Comment: So I must use either a 1K (10% tolerance, 1/2 watt) or a 1K (5% tolerance, 1/2 watt)?

Comment: any equivalent or better